# UNNotification local notification user tap does not trigger delegate when app in background iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, unnotificationrequest

I have an app that alerts the user every x minutes via UNNotification local notification.  If the user does not respond, the iOS lock screen shows a series of banners asking for user response.  Most of the time, a user tap on the banner (after a tap on the Home button) triggers the UNNotification center delegate when the app is in background.  However, **occasionally a user tap on the latest banner does NOT trigger the delegat**e. Note: this is NOT a question about the delegate not receiving a call WITHOUT a user tap: I know this can't be done. Why would the iOS not trigger the app delegate once in a while when the user taps on the action button in the banner? Note: I keep track of the number of pending local notifications and never exceed the system limit of 64.

App delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.

    UNUserNotificationCenter* center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
center.delegate = self;
[center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionAlert + UNAuthorizationOptionSound)
                      completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                          // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
                          NSUserDefaults *storage = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                          if(granted == YES){
                              [storage setBool:YES forKey:@"permission granted"];
                              [storage setBool:YES forKey:@"alert permission granted"];
                              [storage setBool:YES forKey:@"sound permission granted"];
                          }else{
                              NSLog(@"No permission granted");
                              [storage setBool:NO forKey:@"permission granted"];
                          };
                      }];
}

    #pragma mark UNNotificationCenter setup

    UNNotificationAction *acceptAction = [UNNotificationAction actionWithIdentifier:@"ACCEPT_IDENTIFIER" title:NSLocalizedString(@"Continue notifications", nil) options:UNNotificationActionOptionAuthenticationRequired];
    UNNotificationAction *declineAction = [UNNotificationAction actionWithIdentifier:@"DECLINE_IDENTIFIER" title:NSLocalizedString(@"Stop notifications", nil) options:UNNotificationActionOptionAuthenticationRequired];
    UNNotificationAction *doNotDisturbAction = [UNNotificationAction actionWithIdentifier:@"DO_NOT_DISTURB_IDENTIFIER" title:NSLocalizedString(@"Start Do Not Disturb", nil) options:UNNotificationActionOptionAuthenticationRequired];
    NSArray *actions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:acceptAction, declineAction, doNotDisturbAction, nil];
   // NSArray *intentIdentifiers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"none", nil];
    UNNotificationCategory *invite = [UNNotificationCategory categoryWithIdentifier:@"com.nelsoncapes.localNotification" actions:actions intentIdentifiers: @[] options:UNNotificationCategoryOptionNone];
    NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObjects:invite, nil];
    [center setNotificationCategories:categories];
    [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionAlert + UNAuthorizationOptionSound)
                          completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                              // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
                          }];

    #pragma mark UNNotification received in background
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler{
    [center getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler:^(UNNotificationSettings * _Nonnull settings) {
        NSLog(@"notification settings were changed");
        NSUserDefaults *storage = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [storage setBool:YES forKey:KEventLoggerEventNotificationSettingsChanged];
        [storage synchronize];

        if (settings.authorizationStatus != UNAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
            // Notifications not allowed
            NSLog(@"notification settings were changed");
            item.eventDescription = KEventLoggerEventNotificationsNotAllowed;

            // check settings for alert and sound
        }
       // UNNotificationSetting alertSetting = settings.alertSetting;
            if(settings.alertSetting == UNNotificationSettingEnabled){
                [storage setBool:YES forKey:@"alert permission granted"];
                item.eventDescription = KEventLoggerEventAlertsAreAllowed;
            }else{[storage setBool:NO forKey:@"alert permission granted"];
                item.eventDescription = KEventLoggerEventAlertsAreNotAllowed;
            }
            if (settings.soundSetting == UNNotificationSettingEnabled){
                [storage setBool:YES forKey:@"sound permission granted"];
                item.eventDescription = KEventLoggerEventSoundsAreAllowed;
            }else {[storage setBool:NO forKey:@"sound permission granted"];
                item.eventDescription = KEventLoggerEventSoundsAreNotAllowed;
            }

    }];
    NSLog(@"appdelegate - center didReceiveNotificationResponse");


    UNNotification *notification = response.notification;
    if([actionIdentifier isEqual:@"com.apple.UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier"] || [actionIdentifier isEqual:@"com.apple.UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier"]){
    }else{


        BOOL accept = [actionIdentifier isEqual:@"ACCEPT_IDENTIFIER"];
        BOOL stop = [actionIdentifier isEqual:@"DECLINE_IDENTIFIER"];
        BOOL doNotDisturb = [actionIdentifier isEqual:@"DO_NOT_DISTURB_IDENTIFIER"];

        if (accept){NSLog(@"accept");
            [self handleAcceptActionWithNotification:notification];
        }
        else if (stop){NSLog(@"stop");
            [self handleDeclineActionWithNotification:notification];
        }
        else if(doNotDisturb) {NSLog(@"do not disturb");
            [self handleDoNotDisturbActionWithNotification:notification];
        };
    }
```

View Controller:

```
-(UNNotificationRequest *)triggerNotifications: (NSString *)identifier : (NSTimeInterval) interval{
// Note: identifier must be unique or else each new request causes all others to be cancelled.
UNUserNotificationCenter* center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
UNMutableNotificationContent* content = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
content.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Timer expired", nil);
content.body = NSLocalizedString(@"Touch to continue", nil);
NSUserDefaults *storage = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL sound = [storage boolForKey:@"sound permission granted"];
if(sound){
    if([self.selectedSound isEqual:NSLocalizedString(kselectedSoundKeyDoorBell, nil)]){
        content.sound = [UNNotificationSound soundNamed:@"doorbell.caf"];
    }else if ([self.selectedSound isEqual:NSLocalizedString(kselectedSoundKeySystemDefault, nil)]){
        content.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];
    }else if ([self.selectedSound isEqual:NSLocalizedString(kselectedSoundKeyElectronicChime, nil)]){
        content.sound = [UNNotificationSound soundNamed:@"electronic_chime.caf"];
    }else{
        if([self.selectedSound isEqual:NSLocalizedString(kselectedSoundKeyComputer, nil)]){
            content.sound = [UNNotificationSound soundNamed:@"Computer.caf"];
        }
    }
}
content.categoryIdentifier = @"com.nelsoncapes.localNotification";
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDate *fireDate = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval:interval];
// first extract the various components of the date
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSInteger year = [calendar component:NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:fireDate];
NSInteger month = [calendar component:NSCalendarUnitMonth fromDate:fireDate];
NSInteger day = [calendar component:NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:fireDate];
NSInteger hour = [calendar component:NSCalendarUnitHour fromDate:fireDate];
NSInteger minute = [calendar component:NSCalendarUnitMinute fromDate:fireDate];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
components.year = year;
components.month = month;
components.day = day;
components.hour = hour;
components.minute = minute;

// construct a calendarnotification trigger and add it to the system
UNCalendarNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:components repeats:NO];
UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier: identifier content:content trigger:trigger];
[center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error){
    if(error){
    NSLog(@"error on trigger notification %@", error);
    }
}];
}
```

Comment: Perhaps your app is no longer running. You should check the `options` in `didFinishLaunching` to determine if it was launched by a notification tap.

Comment: Paulw11:  that is possible, but I was not able to get iOS to call applicationWillTerminate in the app delegate in order to test that possibility (does not get called when I stop the app from xcode).

Comment: No, that is a hard-kill. `applicationWillTerminate` is not called in that instance

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the problem (and it is in my code). I was calling triggerNotification twice with the same date components (I am only interested in the minute granularity because I use it to trigger an alert at the xth minute). The first call was when the user pressed a start button and the second call was when applicationDidBecomeActive was called in the app delegate. In fact, I did see duplicate notifications in my table. I think, but can't show, that when the system has two UNNotificationRequests pending for the same date components, it only responds to one of the corresponding alert banners. So, when I tapped the latest banner, the delegate was not called. I removed the second trigger and the problem appears to be resolved (i.e., tapping on a button in the banner results in a call to my delegate). Note: even though I was triggering a notification twice for the same date components, I did provide a unique identifier in each request).